# weird behaviour of late import and scopes

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I have just discovered this strange scoping behaviour of both Python 2 and 3. When I'm adding a late import for a sub-module, the main import of toplevel module stops working. Viable example:

```
import os


def start():
    import sys
    print('in modules?', 'os' in sys.modules)
    print('in globals?', 'os' in globals())
    print('in locals?', 'os' in locals())
    print('os =', os)

    import os.path
    os.path.exists('useless statement')


start()
```

The output will be:

```
in modules? True
in globals? True
in locals? False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    start()
  File "test.py", line 9, in start
    print('os =', os)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'os' referenced before assignment
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The same reason you ever get `UnboundLocalError` - `import os.path` assigns to `os` just like `os = 1` would. And why are your imports not at the top of the script?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it just seemed strange that `os` from global scope doesn't get reused *before* it's redefined in the local scope. Also, my imports are importing libraries that can only be safely imported after forking.

Comment: That's the way it always works; Python checks for *subsequent* assignments in a scope, to ensure that the same name doesn't get used for two different things in one scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing special about import statements. It's just how the scoping works in Python. If you're assigning a value to a label, it is local to the scope unless explicitly defined global.

Try this code -

```
a = 2

def start():
    print a

    a = 3

start()
```

This also fails with `UnboundLocalError` as your code because statement `a = 3` makes the label `a` local to function `start`.